# Why do Stripe instruct you to use php -S

Tags: stripe-payments

I am in the UK, where Stripe support is a joke.  I've been instructed to add Stripe as payment gateway on a site I've been working on for some time, and the first thing I see in their PHP documentation is that I should run this command (presumably in PuTTy) "php -S 127.0.0.1:4242".
I understand that this command creates a secondary server for the website with port no 4242.

Nowhere in the Stripe documentation does it explain why this is necessary, or whether this is simply to be used while testing.  The PHP documentation states that this should not be used on a live website.

If anyone can explain what's going on here, I'd be most grateful.

Thank you

I think this page: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/integration-builder can be viewed without logging in.  There's no mention of "php -S" but the assignement: $YOUR_DOMAIN = 'http://localhost:4242'; indicates that you should have started the server before executing this code.

Comment: Can you link to the documentation you're referring to, or does it require logging in? Without context, it's hard to be certain of an answer, but this sounds like instructions for testing a minimum implementation / demo app, rather than for the integration itself.

Comment: Anywhere that you would see that sort of command in Stripe's docs would be a demo/sample app. There's no requirement of using PHP, let alone that specific command, to use Stripe's API.